# why is 0x0 pointing to valid data

Tags: c

While debugging a crash using GDB, I found the program crashes in ASSERT(). The odd thing is that the pointer contains 0x0 which points to valid data.

Sample code:

```
#define MAX_NUM 10;
...
...
assert(x->y != NULL);
assert(x->y->z < MAX_NUM);  <-- Crashes here
```

I can see that 'x' points to a valid address. When I do:

```
(gdb) print x
$16 = 0x841eda3
(gdb) print x->y
$17 = 0x0
(gdb) print *x->y
$18 = {
       ...
       ...
       z = 1;
       ...
}
```

How is this possible? Shouldn't I get "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" error from GDB?

Comment: It's data, but are you sure it's valid data?

Comment: Yes, all the fields of 'y' look sane.

Comment: @aditya: What happens when you `print *(x->y)` - does it give you different results than `print *x->y` and `print (*x)->y`?

Comment: @Brendan `print *(x->y)` gives same result as `print *x->y`. `print (*x)->y` prints `0x0`

Answer (score 0):

What version of GDB?

Core dumps don't always tell the truth. They can be messed up in many ways. I've had core dumps that look valid and are not. I think you simply got lucky that it looks right.